# Is there any way to sync only few tables of two different postgresql database?

Tags: database, postgresql, synchronization, streaming

There are two postgresql table in two different region, and I would like to sync just one table inside both database. Is it possible?

Comment: Perhaps so? https://www.educba.com/postgresql-logical-replication/

Comment: Use publication and subscription logical replication approach.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out his with pgloical.

(Docker PostgreSQL) Bi-directional Replication with pglogical

1. Launch two PostgreSQL container with different port

   1. `docker volume create sync_test_1`
   2. `docker run --name sync_test_1 -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=qwerty1234 -p 5433:5432 -d -v sync_test_1:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres:9.5.23`
   3. `docker volume create sync_test_2`
   4. `docker run --name sync_test_2 -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=qwerty1234 -p 5434:5432 -d -v sync_test_2:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres:9.5.23`
2. Get into PostgreSQL container shell and update and install essential tools

   1. `docker exec -it sync_test_1 /bin/bash`
   2. `apt -y update`
   3. `apt install -y vim`
   4. `apt install -y procps`
   5. do step 1 to 3 with sync_test_2 too
3. Install pglogical package

   1. `apt install -y postgresql-9.5-pglogical`
4. Change postgresql.conf

   1. `vi /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf`

      1. `wal_level = logical`
      2. `track_commit_timestamp = on`enter code here
      3. `shared_preload_libraries = ‘pglogical’`
      4. `max_replication_slots = 10`
5. Restart PostgreSQL

   1. `docker restart sync_test_1`
6. Use pglogical

   1. `create database localharvest`
   2. `psql -U postgres localharvest`
   3. `CREATE EXTENSION pglogical;`
   4. `SELECT pglogical.create_node(node_name := 'db1_local', dsn := 'host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=localharvest user=postgres password=qwerty1234');`
   5. `SELECT * FROM pglogical.replication_set;`
   6. `SELECT pglogical.replication_set_add_table(‘default’, ‘users’);`
   7. `ALTER SEQUENCE users_id_seq RESTART WITH 1 INCREMENT 20;`
   8. `add ‘host replication postgres 172.17.0.1/32 trust’ in /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf`
   9. subscribe each other
   10. `SELECT pglogical.create_subscription(subscription_name := 'db2_subscription', forward_origins := '{}', provider_dsn := 'host=host.docker.internal port=5434 dbname=localharvest user=postgres password=qwerty1234');`

ref: https://eradman.com/posts/active-active-pglogical.html
[From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)
https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/pglogical
https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/resources/pglogical/pglogical-docs/#Replication-sets